# Looking for generic guide on using GPS with my own created maps - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, gps

I have created my own maps of US states that I want to use in my app. I would like to use GPS to reference the user's position as well as various locations I have entered into my database.

Does anyone know of any guides for doing this? My main issue is in converting the known points on my map to something my app can understand and reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to this subject, the wikipedia article on map projection is really good and could provide a starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection